# Can't set correct time

Tags: time

I'm not able to set the correct time on my Ubuntu 14.04 system. It is always nine minutes behind the correct time and makes me being chronically late. Approaches that failed:

1. ntpdate

   ```
   sudo service ntp stop
   sudo ntpdate -s 0.de.pool.ntp.org
   ```

   The command seems to be executed correctly. No change in time offset though.
2. ntpd

   ```
   sudo service ntp restart
   sudo service ntp stop
   sudo ntpd -q -g -x -n
   ```

   restart successful, correct time servers checked in /etc/ntp.conf. No success.
   The command in the third line remains unresponsive.
3. hwclock

   ```
   sudo hwclock --set --date="2014-07-04 11:22:00"
   date
   Fri Jul  4 11:14:59 CEST 2014
   ```

   Executes flawlessly. No change.

My question is related to [System time off by a small amount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20379/system-time-off-by-a-small-amount) but there is no solution given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `date` command to set the time:

```
sudo date -s "2014-07-04 10:53:59"
```

For more info, you can look at the manual page by running:

```
man date
```

If you want to `ntp` and network time, you may just need to set the server as described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/synchronize-the-system-clock-to-network-time-protocol-ntp-under-fedora-or-red-hat-linux.html).

Comment: I have been successful using the GUI interface and set the time manually there, which is probably the same as using date -s. Still I wonder why the automatic sync does not work. I checked the servers and they seem to respond correctly...

Answer (score 1):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` worked for me

Comment: I tried. To no avail. The problem is still nagging me because the internal clock seems to be off a little and after a while I have to readjust with `date -s`

Answer (score 0):

You can only set times in the future, setting past times with `date` command will do nothing and no error will be shown. Ntpd service will correct slowly the time at small steps. It's not like in Windows where you can set any time and see the result immediately.